# How can I get a circular progress bar in Fresco simple drawee view while image is not yet loaded?

Tags: android, fresco

I have used the following code :

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/sdv_single_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitCenter"
            fresco:failureImageScaleType="center"
            fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/spinner_1"
            fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="fitCenter"
            fresco:retryImage="@drawable/spinner_1"
            fresco:retryImageScaleType="fitCenter" />
```

But it didn't work in few cases.

I want that progress bar to be shown till the images get fully loaded from web service.It works when I use same above code for circular drawee view but not applicable for others.

Any help is appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: The code looks OK. When exactly does this not work?

Comment: Its working for loading some images(like profile images roundAsCircle = true) but not for either type of images. I am not at all getting any solution for this since last 4 days.
Any prompt reply is thankful !

Comment: So do you have a concrete example where it is not working. Your answer is very vague. A minimum example with sample images and a description what you expect to see vs what you actually see would be helpful.